# redirect_uri issue when using Keycloak as a reverse proxy and using Spring on a different domain from Keycloak

Tags: spring, nginx, keycloak

I have this setup with Keycloak, Spring Boot and NGINX:

```
api.example.com
example.com
```

NGINX has two config files. One **api.example.com** which points to Spring as a reverse proxy, everything works fine with using the API with Keycloak by using for example Postman/cURL.

I have another one **example.com** that has a reverse proxy to Keycloak. It works fine going to URL `https://example.com/auth` and log in etc. But when trying to access content on my Swagger at `https://api.example.com/v1/docs/index.html` it tries to redirect me to http://api.example.com/sso/login which is two things that are not correct. Firstly the protocol and secondly using the subdomain where Keycloak is not on.

I have set under Valid Redirect URIs `https://example.com/*`. So when a user tried to access that content on my Swagger, should they not be able to redirect to the Keycloak at `https://example.com/auth` and then redirect back when authenticated?

This is my NGINX config for the api.example.com:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass http://private-ip1:8080;
        proxy_set_header    Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_protocol_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port   $server_port;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    }
```

This is my NGINX config for example.com:

```
# Keyclaok
location /auth {
    proxy_pass http://private-ip2:8080;
    proxy_set_header    Host               $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_protocol_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port   $server_port;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
}
```

I don't seem to understand or find information why this is happening. Do anyone have idea how to fix this?

Comment: Your app is redirecting, so your app has wrong code or it is misconfigured. I would say swagger should be available without auth, only API calls needs authentication. App should return 401 for unauthenticated requests and not 3xx redirect.